# count of all event for last 6 hours Zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'd like to know how to count all event for last 6 hours . 
I have two tables eventdate (datetime) and id (int) in my database. 

 I've defined specific database and table in model :

**Event.php :**

```
<?php
class Model_Event extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'event';
    protected $_schema = 'db';
}
```

but I have some problems with controller. I know there is some rows in my table and page must show 10 calls for example but always show me no events 

**SummaryController:**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $eventModel= new Model_Event();
    $select = $eventModel->select()->where ('eventdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR') ;
    $rowCount_op = count($select);
    if ($rowCount_op >1) {
        echo $rowCount_op.'calls';
    }
    else 
        echo 'no events';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
    $select = $eventModel->fetchAll($eventModel->select()->where("eventdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)" ));
```